# SQL add conditional query

Tags: sql-server

In a table in my database I have 12 columns, month_1 .... month_12.

I want to add conditional to my SQL query, if @m = 1 will do

```
CREATE PROCEDURE XemDiem_Top5Month1
    @m INT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM XemDiem
    WHERE (month_1 IN (SELECT TOP (5) month_1
                       FROM XemDiem 
                       GROUP BY month_1
                       ORDER BY month_1DESC))
END
```

if @m = 2 will do

```
CREATE PROCEDURE XemDiem_Top5Month1
    @m INT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM XemDiem
    WHERE (month_2 IN (SELECT TOP (5) month_2
                       FROM XemDiem 
                       GROUP BY month_2
                       ORDER BY month_2 DESC))
END
```

and so on ....

I don't want to write too many queries, so please help

Answer (score 0):

Assign the select query to a string and concatenate your parameter. Finally execute the string.

```
Create proc XemDiem_Top5Month1
@m int
AS
BEGIN
Delcare @query nvarchar(max) 
set @query='SELECT *
FROM XemDiem
WHERE 
(
  month_''+Convert(varchar(10),@m)+'' IN 
  (
    SELECT TOP (5) month_''+Convert(varchar(10),@m)+''
    FROM XemDiem 
    GROUP BY month_''+Convert(varchar(10),@m)+''
    ORDER BY month_''+Convert(varchar(10),@m)+'' DESC
  )
)'
execute(@query)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @ishistoric varchar(100) ='month_1'
(SELECT *
FROM XemDiem
WHERE 
(
 CASE @ishistoric
                  WHEN 'month_1' THEN month_1
                  WHEN 'month_2' THEN month_2
                  ...
                  WHEN 'month_12' THEN month_12
             END  IN 
(
SELECT TOP (5) CASE @ishistoric
                  WHEN 'month_1' THEN month_1
                  WHEN 'month_2' THEN month_2
                  ...
                  WHEN 'month_12' THEN month_12
             END
FROM OSUSR_KIA_PRINTSTICKER 
GROUP BY  CASE @ishistoric
                  WHEN 'month_1' THEN month_1
                  WHEN 'month_2' THEN month_2
                  ...
                  WHEN 'month_12' THEN month_12
             END
ORDER BY CASE @ishistoric
                  WHEN 'month_1' THEN month_1
                  WHEN 'month_2' THEN month_2
                  ...
                  WHEN 'month_12' THEN month_12
             END DESC
)
))
```

Make your remain query just like that and query is based on the provided columns & it will the return respective records for specific column which are passed into the parameter.

Comment: simple,easiest and understandable query for user and developer.